# Quickly seek a location in a file

Tags: c++, c, file, scanf, fseek

I have a file with great amount of numbers,each number is separated by a space.

Such like:    124 1212 5 654 74231 ...

How can I quickly locate the Nth number in this file?

I think `fseek()` may not work because it's measured by bytes,and I can get the  Nth number by:

```
 int i;
 for (i=0;i!=N-1;++i) fscanf(somefile,"%d",&variable);
```

But I guess there might be some way more efficient?

Comment: Once you've found a location in the file using fscanf and the like, you can use ftell() to get the byte location of the file pointer, which you can pass to fseek to return to that location pretty much instantly.

Comment: @MarcB Unfortunately I don't need go back to a number I just found.I may go back after I found hundreds of thousands of other numbers.

Comment: Unless the numbers stored in the file have some property(e.g. they're all 3 digits long), the only way is to read through the entire file until you reach the Nth integer.

Comment: Or index the damn file for later reads, perhaps? :q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create the file, then two other options are:

1. print each number in a fixed width field sufficiently wide to hold the largest number (e.g. "%5d "), then `fseek(somefile,(N-1)*6,SEEK_SET)` to position to number N.
2. If the file doesn't need to be human readable, you could `fwrite()` the integers as binary data instead of ASCII characters to the file and access them with

   ```
   fseek(somefile,(N-1)*sizeof(int),SEEK_SET)
   fread(&variable,sizeof(int),1,somefile)
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Read the whole file once and create an index to some data points in file (for example 1000 points). Each entry in index can map the location in the file to the Nth number starting at that location. Having that index built, every time you are looking for Nth number, first find the closest entry in the index which tells you the closest known point in the file that you can `fseek` to. then perform your search using `fscanf` to find the value. This reduces the search time with the price of using some memory for the index.

an entry in the index can look like:
 (file offset, number N)

index may look like:
 (file offset 1, number 1)
 (file offset 2, number 2)
 ...
 (file offset N, number N)